# Is it bad practice to add a tag to a post to get points to a tag badge even if the tag is relevant?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing-help, tag-badges

I haven't seen this done, but let’s say I want to get the iOS bronze badge. I answer a question, and it gets up voted. Then I think "Hey, I could give that post the iOS badge and get some points to the tag badge. And the tag is totally relevant!". Is it okay if I add the tag to the post, or is that cheating to get the badge?

Comment: Well, banging questions in shape validly isn't considered bad behaviour at all. Bending them is actually.

Comment: Whatever you do, remember to fix *all* the problems of a post if you're going to improve it.

Comment: If it applies and improves the question, I don't see why it could be considered cheating.

Comment: Seems to me like a pretty slimey way to try to obtain a badge. but, if no harm is done (ie the tag is relevant **and adds value**), then... why not add it. I think the reasoning is wrong, but not necessarily the action.

Comment: If you're certain that a question is missing a vital tag, then edit it. And as Jeroen says, please try to fix everything in the question that needs fixing before you submit it, since your edits currently need to be approved by 3 other people. And once you've edited, start working on your answer.

Comment: (cont) Editing a question that you've already answered is less desirable: sometimes people do that to make the question fit their answer better. When done in consultation with the OP that can be legitimate, but sometimes the modified question isn't really in line with the OP's intentions, and I'm sure you can understand why that's bad.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Well, there are the refiner-badges and such. Improving any post is encouraged, whether yours or not, whether you posted there too or not. Which implies not twisting it into something else.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Sure. And I guess one can twist a question before answering it. Of course, such twisting (no matter when it's done) may be due to a misunderstanding, and not intentionally slimy or malicious. But that's why I like to consult with the OP via comments before I attempt to repair their question, and ideally, they'll understand what my suggestions are and do the editing themself.

Comment: Whether it's allowed or not, the bigger question is "is it worth doing that?". Honestly, if it's just so you can get a badge... meh, don't get hung up about it; the badge will come in it's own good time anyway if you keep answering questions (which you will do right? after all, you care about getting more badges...?). So the only effect you'll have is a short-term advance on your badge; you'll get the badge a little earlier than you might have done otherwise. Worthwhile? Just for that? hmmm.... I don't think so.

Comment: @simba well, suppose you are in a self-perceived race with another user for a particular tag badge.  And you have this backlog of 5-10 upvote questions, many of which apply to a particular tag you are only a few dozen points away from getting.  I couldn't imagine who would do it, but you could go and audit your answer backlog for questions that apply to a particular tag, and edit the tag in.  The side effect (if done honestly) is that you more-correctly tag a bunch of questions, which seems to make the gameification aspects of it ok (game goals (unicorn points) aligns with real world goals)

Comment: It's bad practice to do anything with the primary objective of earning points. Focus on helping users rather than accumulating brownie points that have no value other than boosting your self esteem.

Comment: Related questions on meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110675/tag-badge-triggered-by-retagging-potential-for-abuse and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25154/tag-telematics-is-a-new-tag-but-is-currently-synonymous-with-gps

Comment: I brought this issue up on meta.se some time ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99072.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

If the tag is totally relevant to the question, then IMO it's only fair that your answer to that question count toward the respective tag badge. After all, it's a question you answered about the topic. If you answered twenty questions about iOS, and every one of them had any combination of [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode)[objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c)[swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)[uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview)[uisplitviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uisplitviewcontroller) (and all the other UIKit classes) but none of them had [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), you wouldn't have the iOS bronze badge, and that would be a shame. (You might gain an Xcode tag badge, despite the fact that none of the questions pertain to Xcode specifically.)

Just don't go doing this all the time, mmk? ;) Also, make sure you're not doing this with new tags (once you gain the tag creation privilege that is) or tags that are relatively obscure. If a tag is too obscure it's more likely to be seen as a cheap attempt at a badge than an improvement of a question. (That doesn't mean there is a correlation between the two, but that's just how things are.)

While we're on the topic of editing, and badges, the best time to edit a question you've answered is within 12 hours either before or after answering. If you take the time to improve the content of the post along with the tags, your edit will count toward [Explainer/Refiner/Illuminator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-%E2%86%92refiner-%E2%86%92-illuminator/240302#240302). I think as long as you focus more on *improving the post* and less on getting badges, you'll earn them in due time, plus you make the site a better place. Everyone wins.

Comment: *"You might gain an Xcode tag badge, despite the fact that none of the questions pertain to Xcode specifically."* Very important point. Many (most?) questions tagged with [tag:xcode] or any other IDE are not specific to that IDE and should be edited out to be replaced with a more useful tag like the platform this is for ([tag:ios] vs. [tag:osx]).

Comment: I may be wrong (wouldn't surprise me!) but I was convinced that tag scores only count on the *initial* tags for the question so editing in new tags will not affect your score. I can't find a relevant post right now of course...

Comment: (though this may only relate to the dupehammer rather than the tag score)

Comment: @DavidG: Nope, it's dupehammer only.

Comment: What is dupehammer?

Comment: *If you take the time to improve the post's title and/or body, your edit will count toward Explainer/Refiner/Illuminator* assuming your answer has a score of > 0, that is

Comment: @Caleb: BoltClock means that the only case where only the initial tags count is when determining whether a gold-badge user can unilaterally close a question as a duplicate.

Comment: @CalebKleveter [meta-tag:dupehammer]

Comment: Note that you can even lose tag badges due to edits.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Someone misspelled that tag.  It doesn't even have an [umlaut](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/Mj%C3%B6lnir).

Comment: @Tim Castelijns: Yeah, I didn't think I needed to cover every single detail. But I'll throw in a link just for you.

Answer (score 11):

[BoltClock's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307447/641833) answer is good, but leaves out a few key points:

- It is not cheating to add a relevant tag to a question.
- You should only add/modify tags on a question if they are relevant to the question.  Adding an [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag to a question which does not mention iOS and does not require the solution to be limited to iOS is not correct.  For example, if the question is asking about lists in objective-c, adding the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag would be incorrect because programs written in objective-c can be used with multiple operating systems and the answers are not going to require OS specific solutions.
- Tags are to used to improve search engine indexing.  As a result, the tags should describe what is in the post as accurately as possible.  (Yes, they provide other benefits, but the primary purpose is to help people find the questions and answers they are looking for).
- Adding tags to questions just so you can get a badge is incorrect.

Comment: Indeed. (I left out the part about tags being relevant to the question at hand because they were stated in the question already, but it doesn't hurt to spell it out anyways.)

Answer (score 8):

The *whole point* of tag badges is to reward you for correctly tagging questions.

So why would doing this be considered "bad practice"?

I don't think we need to launch into a seminar on Maslow's hierarchy of needs: some people do good for the reward; others do good to do good (though personally I believe that all humans are innately selfish and even if you "do good to do good", knowing you "did good" was the reward, so in fact you did in fact "do good for the reward"; but I digress…).

Either way, if the end result is activity that has been explicitly encouraged, to the extent of adding a reward for it, I don't see how anyone could reasonably claim that it were a "bad practice".

Comment: Do you have a reference for "The whole point of tag badges is to reward you for correctly tagging questions."  I thought the point was to show that you had experience answering questions of a particular type, so you could be trusted with related stuff (like moderation of the tag).

Comment: @Trisped: Well, since the dupehammer came into being I suppose that's true at the extremes, but in general every badge is just a reward. Something to show off. I'm not going to even attempting finding a "reference" for that; it's fundamental to how SE works.