# Do I earn a point each for each tag in a question when my answer to the question is upvoted?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-badges, tag-score

If a question has multiple tags and my answer to the question is upvoted, do I earn a point for each tag in the question? For example, if a question is tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby), do I earn 1 point for the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag badge and 1 point for the [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) tag badge?

Comment: For the purpose of tag badges, yes.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, you do.

Any tags that are added/removed during the lifetime of the question and your answer are subject to this as well. So, for example, if the [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) tag is later removed from the question and replaced with [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf), you lose the points you had gained in [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) from this answer, and you gain the same number of points in [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf).

This is why it's important that questions are tagged correctly: to ensure that [your tag scores are consistent with the questions that you have answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307435/is-it-bad-practice-to-add-a-tag-to-a-post-to-get-points-to-a-tag-badge-even-if-t/307447#307447).

Comment: Well, that and it makes it easier to find stuff.

Comment: Bolt, have we ever looked at tag edit histories to see if people were scamming this ability to raise their tag score in a particular tag through editing past Q/As they have participated in?

Comment: @Chrismas007: Absolutely. It's similar to the practice of mass-tagging old questions with a *new* tag for the Taxonomist badge.

Comment: I have to say I find tag badges rather stupid by themselves - I say that as a user holding "malloc" badge. Basically one can have three badges per each C library function.