# Do answerers gain tag score for tags that are added after the upvote has already been placed?

Tags: support, tags, tag-score

Do answerers gain tag score for tags that are added after the upvote has already been placed?

I recently answered a question wherein my answer received an upvote. In answering the question, I noticed that the question asker had missed a relevant tag for the question. I then personally updated the question to add the missing tag, **after** having received an upvote for my answer to the question.

According to the [**Central Tag Badges FAQ**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work/63836#63836),

> A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1) and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on answers under that specific tag [...]. As well, posts [...] that have been deleted do not count towards your tag score.

In my adding of the new tag, do I now have one more tag score for that tag? Would I lose the tag score if the tag was later deleted?

Assuming the tag score is indeed awarded in retrospect, is there nothing other than the [**2,000 reputation required**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to edit a question stopping an answerer from 'awarding' themselves tag score in such a way?

Comment: There is more, a lot more, there are thirty thousands SO users that will remove nonsensical tags again.  There are two kinds of "reputation", only the second kind is worth pursuing.

Comment: Let's remove nonsensical tags again.

Comment: Good luck awarding yourself some tag score in [featured](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured) with 2k rep.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Do answerers gain tag score for tags that are added after the upvote has already been placed?

Yes; adding a tag to a question where you have an answer scoring 10 will contribute 10 points to your score in that tag.

> Assuming the tag score is indeed awarded in retrospect, is there nothing other than the 2,000 reputation required to edit a question stopping an answerer from 'awarding' themselves tag score in such a way?

No, nothing that is enforced by the system. If the tag fits all of the questions the user is answering, I say [more power to them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307435/is-it-bad-practice-to-add-a-tag-to-a-post-to-get-points-to-a-tag-badge-even-if-t/307447#307447); if you think the tag is redundant (does not need to exist for any number of reasons) or, worse, inappropriate for the questions someone is adding it to, flag their activity for moderator attention.