# Tag badges for self-answers

Tags: support, self-answer, tag-badges

As I know, my tag badge score isn't affected if it was me who added a tag to the question I answered.

Does this mean that self-answers don't usually affect my tag score? Will tag score be affected if other user added a tag to to my question I answered myself?

I've checked several similar questions but I believe none of them addressed both self-answers and tag badges.

Comment: `As I know, my tag badge score isn't affected if it was me who added a tag to the question I answered.` Where did you get this idea from?

Comment: @jpp From my own experience. To my understanding, this was done to prevent users from deliberately improving their tag scores.

Answer (score 6):

Self-answers do count toward tag badges. You can see an example in my profile with the [windows-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) tag, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A106224+%5Bwindows-7%5D+is%3Aanswer). The scores of my four answers add up to 51 as of this posting, of which one self-answer makes up over half the total, which is consistent with the score of 51 shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock?tab=tags&sort=name&page=24).

Also, retags on questions you've answered do affect tag badges (a side effect that [users can take advantage of provided they do it responsibly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307435/is-it-bad-practice-to-add-a-tag-to-a-post-to-get-points-to-a-tag-badge-even-if-t/307447#307447)). You may be getting that mixed up with retags on questions *not* giving you the ability to mark questions as duplicates of questions with the tags you added, with a single vote.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This makes sense, it's easier to abuse tags with dupes rather than with votes.